# Which complexity class $3^{n/3}$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation, complexity-classes

Assuming a problem has complexity $O(3^{n/3})$,

Which is its class of complexity ?

Despite that it is not as $2^{n}$ ,we can say  is an exponential ?

Comment: There was no complexity in the original formulation of the question,
only pure mathematics about asymptotic classes. I artificially
introduced complexity so as not to keep your intended meaning, but the
question was badly worded.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is exponential. Something is exponential if it is $2^{O(n^k)}$ for some $k$. You can write $3^{n/3}$ as $2^{n\frac{\log 3}{3 \log 2}}$, so it fits.

It would be more common to write $(3^{1/3})^n \approx 1.44^n$.

Comment: Answer is almost OK, but you should not accept a math question as a
complexity question when there is no apparent complexity in it. Also,
it is nice to parenthesize exponentials to avoid reading errors. You
assumed left associativity, but the usual reading of exponentials is
[right
associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Examples). So
$3^{{1/3}^n}= 3^{({1/3}^n)}$, which is a double exponential, actually
decreasing with $n$, which is rather unusual for a complexity measure.

Comment: $3^{(1/3)^n} \neq 3^{n/3}$.

Comment: Oh, the penny just dropped. Now I understand what you meant *and* understand @babou's comment. I've edited the answer to correct it. Remember that $x^{y^z}$ means $x^{(y^z)}$, not $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$.

Comment: Exponential could also mean $2^{O(n)}$.